# How to pass ActiveRecord "select" a block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've searched around, and can't find a good solution for this. I'd like to select a list of elements filtered by a block condition and return an ActiveRecord relation object. The best way I've found so far seems messy:

```
def self.only_public
  self.select do |question|
    question.group.public
  end
end
```

This method belongs to the Question model, so I would be filtering question like:

```
Question.all.only_public
```

This returns an array, and I'd rather get back an ActiveRecord object so I can further chain operations.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: what is group.public in this case?

Comment: It's a boolean attribute on the Group model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scope` instead of class method, which will return `ActiveRecord::Relation` instead of `Array`:

```
scope :only_public, -> { joins(:group).where('group.public = true') }
```